# Notation of function spaces - vector vs dimension?

Tags: notation, function-spaces

I have a problem with the notation of function spaces. I append the example where my understanding of the functions space is presented. Please correct me if I did any mistake (and confirm if I did correctly).

Let $f_1,\dots,f_p : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Let define a set of functions $A$ that includes previously defined functions $f_1,\dots,f_p$.

$$
A = \{  f_i, i\in\{1,\dots,p\} \} 
$$

Then I want to define function space $C$ defined with functions in the set $A$ as dimensions. In space $C$ I can now define vector $\mathbf{c} = [c_1, \dots, c_p]$, which I want it to represent function $f(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x})$ with N-dimensional input vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, \dots,x_N]$

$$
f(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^p c_i f_i(\mathbf{x})
$$

---- From this point on my plan is to define a probability distribution over functions space $C$ (each vector in $C$, which is a weighted sum of functions, will have user-defined probability) and do different operations on that. -----

So the question:

- Do I need to introduce any other concept?
- Have I used the correct notation for: a set of functions $A$, function space $C$, vector in function space $\mathbf{c}$, a function $f(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x})$  that is represented by the vector $\mathbf{c}$

If I have done a mistake please correct me.

P.s.: edit to clarify the intent of the question - added future uses - plus fixed set definition.

Comment: Your set $A$ already does not make much sense to me. As written, it says that from the functions $f_i$ (which would need to be defined in context, but are not), you select those that are continuous and where the index $i$ is between $1$ and $p$. I don’t think that’s what you want. More likely, you either just want to say “Let $f_1, \dots, f_p : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions” or you want $A$ to be the set $\{ (f_1, \dots, f_p) | f_i : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb R, \text{$f_i$ continuous, for each $i \in \{1,\dots,p\}$}\}$.

Comment: (long reply) Eike, 
I agree, those functions are user-defined, so mostly arbitrary (specifics are not important in this question). So my goal is to use user-defined functions as dimensions in function space, and use vectors in that space to describe their weighted sum. This will enable me to define a probability distribution over function space for my next steps in the algorithm.
How about other statements about the function space and vectors?  Are those bette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner definition of your set $A$ would simply be
$$
   A = \{ f_1, \dots, f_p \}.
$$

Given the functions $f_1, \dots, f_p$, you can certainly define the subspace $C$ spanned by these functions in the (infinite-dimensional) vector space $C(\mathbb R^N)$ of all continuous functions $\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$. Using words is probably the best way, but you might also write
$$
    C = \operatorname{span} \{f_1, \dots, f_p\} \qquad\text{or}\qquad C = \langle f_1, \dots, f_p \rangle.
$$

This vector space will be at most $p$-dimensional, but its dimension might be lower if the functions $f_1, \dots, f_p$ are not linear independent. If they’re not independent, different “coordinate” vectors $\mathbf c = [c_1, \dots, c_p]$ will yield the same function (and so these vectors wouldn’t be real coordinates); otherwise, i.e. if the $f_i$ are linearly independent, they form a basis of $C$ and the $\mathbf{c}$ are coordinates wrt this basis.

In any case, $\mathbf c$ will not be an element of $C$: it’s a tuple of real numbers whereas the elements of $C$ are functions. The element of $C$ corresponding to $\mathbf c$ is the function
$$
   \mathbf x \mapsto f(\mathbf c, \mathbf x).
$$

Writing these functions as $f(\mathbf c, \mathbf x)$ is fine, though depending on context, $f_{\mathbf c}(\mathbf x)$ or $f(\mathbf c)(\mathbf x)$ might be nicer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I think I understand - so if I try to find analogus example to 2D vectors: when we define high-school vector $a = [a_1, a_2]$ in 2D space with base ?tuples? $\mathbf{i} = [1,0]$ and $\mathbf{j} = [0,1]$, the vector $\mathbf{a}$ represent actually $\mathbf{a} = a_1 \mathbf{i} + a_2 \mathbf{j}$, but because the $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ are tuples, $\mathbf{a}$ becomes $a = [a_1, a_2]$ and can be used as in high-school math as a vector in 2D space and coordinates at the same time.

Comment: The last step is not possible with function space as different function "can not merge into one" (like I did with tuples), so the definition of $\mathbf{c}$ as a vector in the function space is not possible, but only represent the coordinate of the vector.

Comment: P.s.: probably grammar mistake: "are coordinates **wrt** this basis."

Comment: wrt = with respect to. And if the answer was helpful, you can accept it by pressing the checkmark to the left of it. This will remove it from the list of unanswered questions and give me some internet points.